# What is the correct format specifier to print error object in Go: %s or %v?

Tags: go, error-handling, string-formatting

Here is my program.

```
package main

import (
    "errors"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    a := -1
    err := assertPositive(a)
    fmt.Printf("error: %s; int: %d\n", err, a)
    fmt.Printf("error: %v; int: %d\n", err, a)
}

func assertPositive(a int) error {
    if a <= 0 {
        return errors.New("Assertion failure")
    }
    return nil
}
```

Here is the output.

```
error: Assertion failure; int: -1
error: Assertion failure; int: -1
```

In this program, it makes no difference whether I use `%s` or `%v` to print
the `error` object.

I have two questions.

1. Is there any scenario while printing errors where it would make a
   difference for `%s` and `%v`?
2. What is the correct format specifier to use in this case?

Comment: Use %s (but please look up what %v and %s do in the package description of fmt).

Comment: @Volker I know what `%v` and `%s` does. I would like to understand why you recommend `%s` for `error` objects. Can you share the rationale please?

Comment: Less indirection. What gets printed is the output of the `Error()` method and that's a string: Clearer.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

[According to docs](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/):

```
%v  the value in a default format
...
%s  the uninterpreted bytes of the string or slice
```

[Also, more information about `error`](https://blog.golang.org/error-handling-and-go):

> The error type is an interface type. An error variable represents **any
>   value that can describe itself as a string.**

So, treat it as `%s`.

Comment: The only thing that I'd say is perhaps confusing about this is that the Golang team uses `%v` in their blogs: https://blog.golang.org/error-handling-and-go.

Otherwise I think it's probably okay to just use `%s` as well.

Comment: Also more discussion in this issue here:  https://github.com/golang/go/issues/29934, which is somewhat relevant

Comment: Is it worth mentioning the special handling for  format strings ending in `": %s"` followed by an error?  That's very non-intuitive (if it was retained in the language; I'm not sure.)  See @NathanLutterman's citation.

Comment: @Nathan Lutterman `%v` properly formats `<nil>` errors. `%s` outputs something like this when the error is `nil`: `%!s(<nil>)`

Answer (score 0):

%w is what is the correct format specifier according to https://pkg.go.dev/fmt#Errorf

Comment: It's the wrapping directive. You can't use it in `fmt.Println` or `fmt.Printf`. It servers a different purpose rather than simply formatting